# For a symmetric matrix, are eigenvectors of an eigenvalue with a multiplicity $> 1$ orthogonal to each other?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have learned so far that the eigenvectors to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal to each other, given a symmetric matrix.

Does the same apply for eigenvectors of an eigenvalue with multiplicity > 1?

Let's suppose I have an eigenvalue with a multiplicity of 2 and found 2 eigenvectors. Are those orthogonal given a symmetric matrix?

Answer (score 1):

No.

If $\lambda$ is a $k$-fold eigenvalue, then the eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda$ form a $k$-dimensional subspace. Of course, not every pair of independent vectors in such a subspace is orthogonal.

Then again, you can *pick* an orthogonal basis of said eigenspace, thus obtaining an orthogonal basis consisting only of eigenvectors for the whole space.